# Pass the current control to code

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I wonder if there is a way to pass the current control to own code, either to code embedded on the report or to code linked in from another assembly.

Reason is I need to do some custom control drawing (the control will therefore be an image) and it would be handy to query the image size from the control that called.

So instead of putting

```
=Code.DrawOwn(200, 200, ... )
```

I'd like to use

```
=Code.DrawOwn(Me, ... )
```

or

```
=Code.DrawOwn(ReportingItems!Image1, ... )
```

Any way to do that? I fail on defining DrawOwn so that it accepts a parameter of "Control" or "Image" as none of these types seem to exist.

Comment: Talking about this, is there a way to pass a dataset to own code? Again I fail on defining the type in my code the parameter is passed to...

Comment: Have a look at the ReportItem class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.reportrendering.reportitem%28v=sql.120%29.aspx